# Mouse and Keyboard not working on different HDD that I installed

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

Accidentally deleted windows on an hdd, so I replaced the hdd with another one that I had(already had windows). Took a while for it to boot into windows, but when it did I noticed my mouse and keyboard stopped working. For the boot sequence both of them work fine, but once Windows loads in, I can no longer use both the keyboard and mouse. If the problem is the firmware how am I supposed to update it without being able to login? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Send help pls

I already tried:

- restarting
- trying a different keyboard and mouse

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: fyi this is posted to the wrong site. General computing questions belong on [su].

Answer (score -1):

Hit this line inside Run Dialogue Box:
C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe